# Where i need to keep the enums related to the domain object in the domain driven design

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am trying to develop a application using domain driven design. Now i have scenario where a entity changes it status(on of the attribute of the entity) depending on the business rules, and i am putting possible statuses in a enum so Where i need to keep this enum related to the domain object in the domain driven design.

Answer (score 5):

If the status only is used in the domain layer, then you can add it there.  If you have a need to use these values in other layers of your system, then I usually make a separate assembly called something like "Common" which can be used by any layer.  DDD purists might have a problem with that, but to me an enum is not really business knowledge and from a productivity standpoint it is practical compromise, rather than duplicating your enum definitions in every layer.

Comment: Domain driven design standpoint what are the enums? are they value objects?

Comment: No they are not value objects.  You could create a value object called say "CustomerType", but then it wouldn't be an enum any more.  From what I've read, not much guidance on enums is given.  That is why I am comfortable sharing them in my other layers.